# How to make Listview show only 1 record?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm trying to make my Listview show only one record just like how DetailsView does it. At the moment it's showing all my records from the table in my database in a long list, I want to make it show only the latest record from the table. Works for detailsview but not listview.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Nevermind I've figured it out, I needed to add a datapager and set the page size to 1.

     `<asp:DataPager ID="Number1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1"
       PageSize="1">
       </asp:DataPager>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should filter your datasource so your listview shows only one result, something like

```
mylistView.DataSource = List<ListItems>[List.Count-1];
mylistView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this can do it (set datasource of listview to query):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MyColumns(s) FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
```